# Execute function after async function is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, async-await, jira-rest-api

I have three functions, which need to be executed one after another

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Async function
    getAllTask();
    // Need to call after above function completed its process
    loadTasks();
    initView();
    listenEvents();
});

async function getAllTask(){
    // For this ap.request alone I used await, Because of await keyword I make this function as async
    await AP.request(...);

}
```

I want to execute the all other functions after the `getAllTask()` function is completed its process.
But the function `getAllTask()` is async. Please help me to solve this.

Anybody facing the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use await too when you call getAllTask(); and make function async so code will wait function to finish

```
$(document).ready(async function(){
    // Async function
    await getAllTask();
    // Need to call after above function completed its process
    loadTasks();
    initView();
    listenEvents();
});

async function getAllTask(){
    // For this ap.request alone I used await, Because of await keyword I make this function as async
    await AP.request(...);

}
```

Also you could implement Promise object => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
 to finish your async function with resolve() here an example

```
 $(document).ready(async function(){
        // Async function
        await getAllTask().then((data)=>{
            //Here you will get resolve(data)
            console.log(data)
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err)
                //here you will get error given
        })
        // Need to call after above function completed its process
        loadTasks();
        initView();
        listenEvents();
    });

    async function getAllTask(){
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        // For this ap.request alone I used await, Because of await keyword I make this function as async
            await AP.request(...).then((data)=>{
                //It will resolve data, same as return
                resolve(data)
            }
            .catch((err)=>{
                //It will return the error given
                reject(err)
            };
        }
    }
```